# Nullish Coalescing operator in Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was trying to convert a binary tree to array and I am confused in it.
This is the code I am writing:

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
    var rc=rc??[];
    if(root==null)
        return ;
    rc.push(root.val);
    maxDepth(root.left);
    maxDepth(root.right);
    return ((rc.length-1)/2)+1;
};
```

So the problem is that my array always contains 1 element. But according to my understanding , won't after pushing the first element in rc , the nullish coalescing operator will assign the value of rc to the array?
Why is it essentially resetting the array?

Comment: `rc` is `undefined` in this context because `var rc` declares a new variable `rc` and initializes it with `undefined`. If `rc` is a global variable, either use `rc = rc ?? [];` without the `var`, or use a different variable name.

Comment: You never add more than one element in the array. The recursive calls will make a new array and then add to their own. Moreover, neither do you give any data for the recursive calls to manipulate, nor do you use their return values. Effectively, their only purpose is to take up some CPU time. You can just remove them and it'd be very obvious why you get that result.

Comment: @SebastianSimon So , every recursion call will make a new execution context and rc is undefined in it. Is that right??

Comment: Recursion doesn't mean the call "rewinds back to the start". It's a plain normal function call. Whether you call `maxDepth()` for the first time or from within `maxDepth()` the *exact same* steps will be taken to execute the function. Create variables, run the code to completion, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ , so rc is undefined everytime and I get an empty array?

Comment: Correct. When `maxDepth()` is called, the  `var rc` creates a variable with the value `undefined`, so `rc??[]` will always jump to create a new array.